# "The Wi-Fi network could not be found"

Tags: networking

I've a problem with Ubuntu 18.4 and the Wi-Fi.

Ubuntu is installed on the Jetson Nano developer board. When I boot/reboot the device, it connects automatically to the wifi network. Fine.

But I have to change the wifi network to a second one, which is running at my home... I tried to switch to the new wifi network via Ubuntu desktop, nmtui and nmcli. But every time I get the error message: "The Wi-Fi network could not be found" even though it was displayed in the list/terminal...

When I now try connect to my "normal" wifi network, which was running after the boot/reboot, I get the same error message and I can't connect to any wifi network. After rebooting it connects to the "normal" wifi connection and everything is starting again.

Do you have an idea?

Thanks, 
Lars

Comment: First thing that comes to mind: Is there a space or another special character in the network name?

Comment: No, no space or special character in the ssid... If it's important, I'm using the Edimax 7811UN USB stick and it's, as said, really good working until I want to change the network.

Comment: 1) Are you running these commands as root? 2) Is the output of `sudo iwlist scan` what you expect?

Comment: I tried it with sudo, too, but it didn't work. The output of sudo iwlist scan shows all wifi networks that I find also with my mobile phone.